# mongoose save by reference multiple document

Tags: express, mongoose

I'd like to make new document by reference of two documents.

```
**app.post('/student_badge/register', async (req, res) => {
const name = req.body.name;
const category = req.body.category;

People.find({name: name}, '_id', function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    var obj = eval(doc);
    id = obj[0]._id;
  })

  Badge.find({category: category}, 'points title', function (err, doc)  {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      var obj2 = eval(doc);
      points = obj2[0].points;
      title = obj2[0].title;
      console.log(title + "  " + points);
  });


  data = {
    id: id,
    title: title,
    points: points
  }


  console.log("data: " + data);   
  const sbadge = new StudentBadge(data);

  sbadge.
  save()
  .then(result => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Post created successfully!',
      post: result
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});**
```

But I cannot call three variables like id, title, points to store them in 'data'.
How can I call variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because the variables you are trying to access, i.e. `id, title, points`, are being set on a callback function that gets executed asynchronously.

I would suggest using async/await instead of callbacks so that you can thereafter use the data from the other documents you are querying in the same function. In addition, I suggest to use `findOne()` since you only access the first entry in db.

Something like the example below should work: (I have abstracted the middleware in a separate function for clarity to use with express)

```js
const createStudentBadge = async (req, res, next) => {
  const {name, category} = req.body;

  let person, badge;
  try {  
    person = await Person.findOne({name}); // shortcut for {name: name}
    badge = await Badge.findOne({category});
  } catch(err) {
    // handle error
  }

  if (!person || !badge) {
    // Handle case where no document has been found in db
    // This case will not throw an error when calling find()
  }

  data = {
    id: person._id,
    title: badge.title,
    points: badge.points
  }

  const studentBadge = new StudentBadge(data);

  try {
    await studentBadge.save();
  } catch(err) {
    // handle error
  }

  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Post created successfully!',
    post: studentBadge
  });
}

app.post('/student_badge/register', createStudentBadge);
```

If you wanted to perform the querying in parallel, you could make use of `Promise.all()` and run both queries at the same time. More info can be found at [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)